# delete json objects, if valued matching

Tags: python, json

I want to delete json objects if value found in the json body. Please see below code and json body. I tried in python but getting error : [*TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*]

```
   import json
   import sys
   key = ['1']
   myData = [
     {
  "id": 1,
  "modifiedBy": "admin",
  "fields": {
    "Application": "1",
    "Endtermin": 23011990
    }
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "modifiedBy": "admin",
  "fields": {
    "Application": "2",
    "Endtermin": 11021990
    }
  }
  ]
 #  delete json objects.
 [x for x in myData['fields'] if x["Application"] != 'key']
```

For example : In the json body, I will look for the Application value, when matching with key, then I want to delete json objects. Here i want to delete first json objects because key value is matching with Application value.

My results looks like here.

```
    myData = [
       {
         "id": 2,
         "modifiedBy": "admin",
         "fields": {
            "Application": "2",
            "Endtermin": 11021990
          }
      }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed several things up here.

1. `myData` is a list, therefore you cannot access any item in it via a string (that's what the error tells you)
2. You should not check for `'key'`, but for `key[0]`
3. `key` does not need to be a list

So here's how to fix this:

```
import json
import sys
key = "1" # point 3 from above
myData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "modifiedBy": "admin",
    "fields": {
      "Application": "1",
      "Endtermin": 23011990
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "modifiedBy": "admin",
    "fields": {
      "Application": "2",
      "Endtermin": 11021990
    }
  }
]
#  delete json objects. This overwrites myData
myData = [x for x in myData if x["fields"]["Application"] != key] # points 1 and 2
```

If you really need `key` to be a list because it may contain several keys, I'd suggest following changes:

```
keys = ["1", "5"]
# myData is still the same
# ...
myData = [x for x in myData if x["fields"]["Application"] not in keys]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should yield your desired filtering

```
[x for x in myData if x['fields']['Application'] not in key]
```

iterates over the list of entries in `myData` and check for each entry `x` whether it's property `x['fields']['Application']` is not in the list of `key` which you want to filter

**Full code:**

```
import json
import sys
key = ['1']
myData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "modifiedBy": "admin",
    "fields": {
      "Application": "1",
      "Endtermin": 23011990
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "modifiedBy": "admin",
    "fields": {
      "Application": "2",
      "Endtermin": 11021990
    }
  }
]
#  delete json objects.
myData2 = [x for x in myData if x['fields']['Application'] not in key]

print(myData2)
```